# Can I say "Look, the bus comes" to mean "Look, here comes the bus"?

Tags: inversion

I know if I add the word "here" at the end as "Look, the bus comes here", it won't sound right, but what if I simply say "Look, the bus comes"? Does it mean the same as "Look, here comes the bus"? Does it sound natural?

Comment: The first two sound unnatural. The third is good, but you can also say "Here comes the bus".

Answer (score 5):

The way you are using the simple present tense to describe a current event

> Look, the bus comes.

is **probably the most obvious giveaway that you are not a native speaker of English**.

Languages like German

> Der Bus kommt.

or Spanish

> El autobús viene.

commonly use simple present to express that an event is happening *right now*, but in English we do that with the present continuous:

> The bus is coming.

Moreover, if you use the simple present you are likely to suggest that the event is durable and general. For example

> Geese fly.

means that the act of flying is a property of geese, while

> Geese are flying.

means you should look up in the sky right now if you want to see some geese.

Comment: Hmm. I think you need to be a bit more explicit. You don't actually say that they need the present continuous/progressive and you don't say that "the bus is coming" would be preferable. At the moment the learner needs to cryptically infer this from the answer ;)

Comment: @Araucaria: I think my first sentence covers that ground pretty well, though perhaps not baldly enough for your taste.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, you should **rephrase** it to;

> "... Look, the bus **is coming**."

The sentence means **exactly** the same as "Look, **here comes** the bus". This works due to talking in the **present tense**. Both are **casual** and used **socially**. The **alternate way** you provided sounds **awkward and unnatural**, I would stick to the sample I provided, although it is **clear** that you mean it the same way.

Comment: **Why** the random **use** of bold?

Comment: I always bold words / phrases that I think are important out of all of them, so  it's easier to skim through the text without missing key parts. Good for lengthy answers.

Comment: Good answer, though I agree the bolded words are more distracting than informative -- but it's your choice of style.

Comment: I find it helpful myself, so I'm only reciprocating what I like to see. If general consensus says it's distracting, I'll remove the habit :-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers that

> The bus **is coming**

is the most natural way to express its imminent arrival.  However, it is possible to use the simple present in an *ironic* way as if to express some kind of special or momentous event.  This is because of the now-archaic *third-person singular simple present indicative* form of the verb, "cometh", now only commonly seen in texts like The Bible:

> I am the living bread which **cometh** down out of heaven, that a man may eat thereof and not die.

If you want to be appropriately melodramatic, you could say something like:

> **Lo**!  The bus **cometh**!

but it is acceptable to shift this to the modern conjugation, and say (with appropriately dramatic tone)

> There!  The bus comes!

Again, this particular use is dramatic, archaic, and can be satirical -- but it may be helpful to be familiar with it, in case you see it in a movie.  For example:

> [The birds!  The birds!  **He rises!**](https://youtu.be/eLTlfljynV4)  *Moby Dick* (1956)

Comment: Speaking of _Moby Dick_, would **'Thar she blows!'** be appropraite for an approaching bus?

Comment: @LarsMekes  It would probably be funnier if the bus was predominantly white.